# Sent form (list object) to controller AJAX MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I want sent  form (list of object) with ajax. But the function serialize() in JS doesnt read in controller

JS File:

```
    function save() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ocena/AddOcene",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            id: $("#KlasaDDL option:selected").val(),
            dodaj: $('#formOceny').serializeArray()
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#load').html(html);
        }
    })
}
$(function () {

    var llBtn = $('#saveForm');
    llBtn.click(function () {
        save();
    });
});
```

In controller I have parametrs:

```
 public ActionResult AddOcene(string id, List<Dodaj_ocene> dodaj)
```

View:

```
@model List<biblioteka.Dodaj_ocene>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formOceny" }))
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model[0].Przedmiot, (SelectList)ViewBag.Przedmiot, "--Dostępne przedmioty--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @*@Html.DropDownList(m => Model[0].Przedmiot, *@
    <p>Wprowadź rodzaj</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[0].Rodzaj, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <p>Wprowadź Opis</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[0].Opis, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <p>Wybierz wagę ocen:</p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[0].Waga, new SelectListItem[] {
                    new SelectListItem{ Value = "5", Text = "V", Selected = Model[0].Waga == 5  } ,
                    new SelectListItem{ Value = "4", Text = "IV", Selected = Model[0].Waga == 4  } ,
                    new SelectListItem{ Value = "3", Text = "III"  , Selected = 

           }, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <br /> <br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>    
        </tr>
        @for (var index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model[index].ImieNazwisko </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[index].Wartosc, new SelectListItem[]{
                    new SelectListItem{ Value = "0", Text = "Brak oceny", Selected = Model[index].Wartosc == 0  } ,

                    new SelectListItem{ Value = "1", Text = "1"  , Selected = Model[index].Wartosc == 1  }

           } , new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div></div> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="saveForm">Zapisz</button>
    </div>
}
```

I would be very grateful for a Apparently

Comment: You need to show some of the view - the `@model ???` declaration, the dropdownlist, and the loop your using inside your form (just one of 2 properties)

Comment: @model List<biblioteka.Dodaj_ocene> 
Id from drop down list can read in Controller but I havent got idea how read list to Controller. 
I want serialize this (@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formOceny" }))) and read in Controller (dodaj)

Comment: You need to edit your question with the code.

Comment: Ok I edited the question.

Comment: That is an awful way to generate your view (us a view model and build your SelectLists in the controller, not the view. Just use `data: $('#formOceny').serialize(),` and remove the `string id` parameter. Your collection will be correctly bound and you do not even have a form element with `id="KlasaDDL"` so not clear what the extra value you tryng to pass is